# Magnific-popup when live uses, double click

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, radio-button, magnific-popup

I created one popup with ajax, when reload radio button with calls ajax, I have press double click for magnific popup response correctly.

When press **Enabled address**, the radio buttons reload through ajax. I have to press 2 times.

My code example:

http://codepen.io/alexd2/pen/xZOOBN

Steps:

1. Press radio button **Punto**, show modal popup.
2. Press set.
3. Input text fill automatic with information of popup.
4. Press Enabled address.
5. Try again press radio button **Punto** (I have to press 2 times.)

The ideal is press 1 time.

My code example

```
<div id="my">   
    <form action="" name="frm" id="frm">
        <div class="select-radio">
            <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" id="s_method_puntoshipping_free"> Free
            <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" id="s_method_puntoshipping_puntoshipping" data-mfp-src="#map-pd"> Punto
        </div>      
    </form>
    <script>
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(function(){
            jQuery( document ).on("click","#s_method_puntoshipping_puntoshipping", function(){
                jQuery("#s_method_puntoshipping_puntoshipping").magnificPopup({
                    callbacks: {
                        open: function() {
                            //INIT

                            //CLOSE
                        }
                        ,
                        beforeClose: function() {
                            var location=jQuery("#selectedLocationPunto").val();
                            var cp=jQuery("#selectedPostalCodePunto").val();
                            var address = jQuery("#selectedAddressPunto").val();

                            jQuery("#billing\\:city").val(location);
                            jQuery("#billing\\:postcode").val(cp);
                            jQuery("#billing\\:street1").val(address);                          
                            jQuery("#s_method_puntoshipping_puntoshipping").prop("checked", true);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            jQuery( document ).on( "click", "a#lnk-select", function() {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    jQuery(".mfp-close").click();
                }, 500);
            });

        });
    </script>
</div>
<div id="address" class="check-address">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chck" id="chck"> Enabled address
</div>
<div class="inputs">
    <input type="text" id="billing:city" value="">
    <input type="text" id="billing:postcode" value="">
    <input type="text" id="billing:street1" value="">
</div>
<div id="map-pd" class="mfp-hide" style="padding: 40px; background: #FFF; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; width: 20%; min-height: 200px;">

    <div id="puntoWidget">
        <input type="text" id="postalcode" name="postalcode" value="6635"><br/>
        <input type="text" id="address" name="address" value="Street Jhon Snow"><br/>
        <input type="text" id="location" name="location" value="N/A"><br/>
        <button name="setvalue" id="setvalue">Set</button>
    </div>
    <input id="selectedPostalCodePunto" type="hidden">
    <input id="selectedAddressPunto" type="hidden">    
    <input id="selectedLocationPunto" type="hidden">    
</div>

<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery("#setvalue").on('click', function(){
            jQuery("#selectedPostalCodePunto").val(jQuery("#postalcode").val());
            jQuery("#selectedAddressPunto").val(jQuery("#address").val());
            jQuery("#selectedLocationPunto").val(jQuery("#location").val());

            setTimeout(function(){
                jQuery(".mfp-close").click();
            }, 500);
        });

        jQuery("#chck").on('change', function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
              url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/alexd2/yd5jegm9/show/",
              cache:false,
              beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                jQuery( "#my" ).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif">');
              }
            })
            .done(function( data ) {
                jQuery( "#my" ).html( data );
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Where are the error?

Comment: Unable to find 'set' in step 2.

Comment: I also see that no `type` has been defined. Per the docs: `By default, Magnific Popup has 4 types of content: image, iframe, inline, and ajax. There is not any “auto-detection” of type based on URL, so you should define it manually.`

Comment: What should `jQuery("#chck")` do when changed. This does not make any sense.

Comment: I got a working test here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/j4pdo3tg/2/

Comment: @Twisty, the jQuery("#chck") is important, this is only the small code of one more big. (Magento).